# In Mongo Sum for each array elements after finding Max from each

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I am stuck on something and need your help.
I want to perform a mongo aggregate query on the below collection so that I can get the Total Weight as Sum of Max of each subarray list from boxWeight1 and boxWeight2, i.e, `sum+=max[boxWeight1,boxWeight2] for each array item in boxList array` and other fields should be projected as it is but with different Key Names.

Collection is somewhat like this...

```
{
     _id: '',
     email: 'yugal121@gmail.com',
     number: 12345,
     boxDetail: {
        boxname: 'package_yugal',
        boxList: [
            {
               boxWeight1: '4.0',    //this is max here. so it will be added
               boxWeight2: '2.0'
            }.
            {
               boxWeight1: '4.0',
               boxWeight2: '8.0'     //this is max here. so it will be added
            } 
            {
               boxWeight1: '0.0',
               boxWeight2: '2.0'     //this is max here. so it will be added
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

So the result for the above collection after performing the query should be somewhat like this:

```
{
    'User Mail': 'yugal121@gmail.com',
    'Order Number': '12345',
    'Total Weight': '14.0'   // 4 + 8 + 2 
}
```

I hope you have understood my question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
           {
              $unwind : "$boxList"
           },
           {
              $project : {
                           "email" : 1,
                           "number" : 1,
                           "maxWeight" : { $cond : { if : { $gt : 
                               ["$boxList.boxWeight1","$boxList.boxWeight2"]} , 
                                                    then : "$boxList.boxWeight1" , 
                                                    else : "$boxList.boxWeight2"}
                                         }
                         }
            },
            {
                $group : { 
                            _id : "$_id" , 
                            Total : {  $sum : "$maxWeight" }, 
                            email : {  $first : "$email" },
                            number : {$first : "$number"}
                        }
           },
           {
               $project : { 
                            "User Mail" : "$email" , 
                            "Order Number" : "$number",
                            "Total Weight" : "$Total",
                            _id : 0
                          }
            }
  ]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried somewhat like this only. I have posted my answer above.
Thanks for answering it. Now I am sure that my query is somewhat in correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{   
    $project: {
         email: '$email',
         number: '$number',
         boxList: '$boxDetail.boxList'
    },
    {    $unwind: '$boxList'   },
    {
         $group: {
             _id: '$_id',
             'Total Weight': {
                $sum:{
                        $max:['$boxdetail.BoxActualWeight', '$boxdetail.BoxDimWeight']
                    }
              },
              'User Email': {
                $first: '$email'
              },
              'Order Number':{
                $first: '$number'
              }
         }

    }
}])
```

This gives result with _id column with it. Which can be removed with another projection after it.